# Remove characters from an OFL font and use it on a web site

Tags: software

I found the OFL font [Sarabun](https://www.f0nt.com/release/th-sarabun-new/) on the web and I want to use it on my web site. The ttf file is quite large because it contains letters of the thai language.

I removed the unnecessary characters using the pyftsubset command of fonttools.

According to the OFL a modified version must have a different name so I renamed the new font to PaperStroke.

It would also be possible to use the original name if [Function Equivalence (FE)](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL_web_fonts_and_RFNs) is given. But because the font name doesn't play a big role for me I prefer to rename the font.

According to the [OFL-FAQ](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#43cecb44), a font should contain a FONTLOG which lists the original version and the modifications. The original font (Sarabun) has no FONTLOG. Should I create one?

On my website I want to create a credits section which tells the user that the PaperStroke font is licensed under the OFL and is based on the Sarabun font.

Is this the right way?
I modified the ttf version of the font. Is this ok or should I rather look for the source code?
I also don't want to use Google Fonts because i prefer to host the font on myself.